# Quantize grayscale images

Tags: r, image, image-processing, grayscale, quantization

I have grayscale images which I want to quantize to different gray levels.

To be more precise, in the [EBImage package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html), we have a function `equalize()` which has an argument `levels`. we can set `levels` value to 256 or 128 or 64 etc to quantize our grayscale images. (But the `equalize()` function will perform a histogram equalization of the given grayscale image, which is not preferred for my current situation)

Can somebody suggest a formula or a function which we can use to change the number of gray levels in the given grayscale image.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the format in something continous.
Now pseudocode.

`int x = (int) (value / (Quantisation));
(new format) y = x * Quantisation;`

It is also possible to compress images that lousy way.

Answer (score 1):

The default image data representation in *EBImage* is a continuous range between 0 and 1. In order to quantize an image to a given number of `levels`, first convert it to integers in the range of `0:(levels-1)`, and then back to `0:1`, as in the `quantize` function from the following example.

```
library(EBImage)

## sample grayscale image
x = readImage(system.file("images", "sample.png", package="EBImage"))

## function for performing image quantization
quantize = function(img, levels) round(img * (levels-1)) / (levels-1)

## quantize the image
y = quantize(x, levels = 8) 

## show the result
display(y)
```

[image]